# Track attribute change of NSManagedObject

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I'm looking for a way to track the attribute change of an NSManagedObject.

Currently I use a NSNotifactionCenter to see the changes of my managedobjectcontext:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(handleDataModelChange:) name:NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification object:self.managedObjectContext];
```

It fires the handleDataModelChange Methode which looks like this:

```
- (void)handleDataModelChange:(NSNotification *)note
{
    NSSet *updatedObjects = [[note userInfo] objectForKey:NSUpdatedObjectsKey];

    if (updatedObjects.count > 0) {
        for (NSManagedObject *obj in updatedObjects.allObjects) {
            NSLog(@"Object updated: %@ with values:",obj.entity.name);
            NSDictionary *theAttributes = [self getAllAttributesOf:obj];
            for (NSString *attributeName in theAttributes) {
                NSLog(@"Name: %@ : %@",attributeName,[obj valueForKey:attributeName]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This logs the new attributes of the object if it changed. How can I achieve a way to get the old attribute values as well?

Comment: Maybe you could try to fetch the old value from the store?

Comment: @Mundi Are you suggesting execute a separate fetch request?

Comment: Of course. How else would you fetch it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [NSManagedObject Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObject_Class/Reference/NSManagedObject.html):

#### changedValues

Returns a dictionary containing the keys and (new) values of persistent properties that have been changed since last fetching or saving the receiver.

#### changedValuesForCurrentEvent

Returns a dictionary containing the keys and old values of persistent properties that have changed since the last posting of `NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification`.

Comment: changedValues returns a dictionary with one key which contains the new value for the relationship, but changedValuesForCurrentEvent returns an empty set. Any ideas?